# java.util.logging print file name

Tags: logging, java.util.logging

How do I print the name file of where the logger was called in java.util.logging?

More specifically I need for each logging call I need to print the line number, function name, and file name. Is it possible in java.util.logging?

Answer (score 0):

The line number and file name are not stored in the LogRecord.  If you are not performing any thread handoff via the MemoryHandler or otherwise you can infer the caller in a custom formatter using StackTrace or StackWalker.

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class CallSiteFormatter extends java.util.logging.Formatter {
    
    private final java.util.logging.Formatter target = new SimpleFormatter();
    
    public CallSiteFormatter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        StackTraceElement stack = inferCaller();
        return String.format("%s%s", target.format(record), stack);
    }

    private boolean isPrintImplFrame(String cname) {
        for (Class<?> k = getClass(); k != java.util.logging.Formatter.class; k = k.getSuperclass()) {
            if (k.getName().equals(cname) || cname.startsWith("java.util.logging.")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private StackTraceElement inferCaller() {
        StackTraceElement stack[] = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace();
        int ix = 0;
        while (ix < stack.length) {
            StackTraceElement frame = stack[ix];
            String cname = frame.getClassName();
            if (isPrintImplFrame(cname)) {
                break;
            }
            ix++;
        }

        while (ix < stack.length) {
            StackTraceElement frame = stack[ix];
            String cname = frame.getClassName();
            if (!isPrintImplFrame(cname)) {
                return frame;
            }
            ix++;
        }

        return new StackTraceElement(CallSiteFormatter.class.getName(), "format", null, -1);
    }
}
```

Sample output looks like:

```
May 20, 2022 06:01:04 AM LogTest main
INFO: This is a test
LogTest.main(LogTest.java:14)
```

You can change the way this looks by calling the methods on the StackTraceElement instead of just the toString like I'm doing here.